# Exclude jar being added in eclipse .classpath on "mvn eclipse:Eclipse" command

Tags: maven

I have to exclude one jar being added in eclipse .classpath file on running mvn eclipse:eclipse command. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exceludes parameter as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#excludes

See also:

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: I tried using excludes like this.<excludes><exclude><groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                      <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId></exclude></excludes> but it doesn't worked. Is this a right way to add above tags in <plugin> - > <configuration> section of pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This kinda late but this is for those still using mvn eclipse:eclipse and what to exclude some dependencies in eclipse classpath entry

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration> 
    <excludes>
      <exclude>org.springframework:spring-asm</exclude>
    </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```